# alt+tab moves windows between workspaces and crashes unity

Tags: 11.10, unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I have recently been using multiple workspaces in unity but have run into a bug that is making it very difficult to do this effectively.

The problem is with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. When I am focused on a window that is not in the primary (top-left) workspace one of two things happens:

1. Unity restarts (the launcher and menu bar disappear and screen flashes blank before everything reappears) and all of my windows are moved to different workspaces. The focused window is always moved to the primary workspace and other windows are typically moved one workspace to the left. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> will usually function normally after this.
2. Unity completely crashes. The windows in the current workspace are still there, but the launcher and menu bar are gone, I cannot switch between workspaces, and none of the hotkeys work.

The same issues occur when using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> as well.

I have installed **ccsm**, but have made only minor adjustments with it. I am still using the Unity switcher. I actually uninstalled **ccsm** hoping that would resolve the issue, but the issue persists.

Is there some resolution to this issue? I like Unity and want to keep using it, but having to use the mouse to switch between programs is irritating and enough reason to switch to Gnome.

Comment: Before you press alt+tab click first on the desktop.

Comment: I tried clicking on the desktop first, but the result is the same.

Comment: try to run "fsck" in the terminal

Comment: if you using compiz just try to reinstall all settings to default

Comment: I have this problem too, I use AMD (ATI) propietary Driver. Maybe this is the reason of the crash? :(
But there's an odd behavior though, because ALT+TAB works some times, regardless of how many workspaces or applications I'm running, and other times it just dies.

Comment: I have same problem. I've got Ubuntu 11.10 installed on ASUS netbook S101. Very annoying. It never happened before I upgraded to 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Did it run smoothly before?, if yes try to reset settings using Ubuntu tweak's desktop recovery tool, If no try to use another switcher, if problem exists, you may have some issues with CCSM try reinstalling CCSM (complete remove including config files)

Comment: I think you have to purge CCSM to remove the config files.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue was faced by us and we managed to fix it by using several solutions.

Run fsck as mentioned first. In our case it found something to be fixed.

While seeking CCSM we found MyUnity as the appropriate customization tool, and encountered errors with meeting the dependencies. Which appears to be the cause of error here.

Anyways, several searches made us do "sudo apt-get install -f" and we managed to get this problem resolved after a restart.

This would help. We are new with Ubuntu too and are loving it.

TNG- Cheers from Chandigarh.

Comment: not sure what exactly helped, but running `fsck` and installing `MyUnity` seem to have fixed it for me